# In-lining C arguments to an array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to be able to pass a variable number of objects in C to a function, by wrapping it in an array. As an example:

```
void test(int arr[]) {}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    test({1, 2});
}
```

But I'm not certain how to go about creating an in-line array, and googling the problem leads to a lot of unrelated results.

I've also tried these variations:

```
test(int[]{1, 2});
test(int[2]{1, 2});
```

However have not found any reasonable way to create this. How is this possible in C?

As a note, I cannot use `varargs`.

**Edit:**

The code used and the compiler error:

```
void test(int ex[]) {}

int main() {
    test(int[]{1, 2});
}
```

> test.c:4:10: error: expected expression before 'int'

Comment: what problem (***exactly***) did you encounter?  Did it fail to compile? *(then you must post the compiler error!)* Did it crash at Runtime? *(then you must describe the runtime crash!  What type? what message? what line?)*

Comment: Adding to question for posterity

Comment: What OS are you using? Note that the Visual Studio C Compiler is C89 since William III decided to ignore C99 and everything it followed, where support for more literals was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt was very close - all you needed is to add parentheses:

```
test((int[]){1, 2});
//   ^     ^
// Here    |
//     and here
```

This is the compound literal syntax for arrays, which is added in C99. Similar syntax is available for `struct`s, and it also requires parentheses around the type name.

Comment: Thanks, casting seems to have fixed this.

Comment: @Rogue This looks like casting, but it's the compound literal syntax of C99 that looks exactly like casting followed by a curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

```
void test(int arr[])
{
    /* some body */
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {1, 2};
    test(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might also provide a sentinel or an array count somehow.